# string from excel and Import to Lotus Notes document as datevalue

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have excel column value as "10/08/2017" as string but I would like to convert that as date time and format it with d/mm/yyyy format, but below code gives me error of type mismatch.

```
Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue(reader.header(k),  Format(cdat(reader.GetCurrentValue(k)),"d/mm/yyyy"))
```

I am using Notes 9 and on windows 10.

Please note that reader.GetCurrentValue(k) is not blank and it gives proper field name from loop

Please assist what is wrong here.

Comment: What happens if you have Format(cdat("10/08/2017","d/mm/yyyy")) instead?

Comment: This works, but the value coming from excel is also string, what is wrong here?

Comment: If I am below above I am getting above error. call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue(reader.header(k),  Format(cdat(reader.GetCurrentValue(k)),"d/mm/yyyy"))Type mismatch method CoerStrToNum : String Found Double expected

Comment: I tried to putting msgbox typename(eader.GetCurrentValue(k)) and it gives me string

Comment: Is it giving STRING, or STRING() ?

Comment: it gives only STRING

Comment: And how about for reader.header(k)?

Comment: Yes that is string too.

Comment: What does `Print TypeName(reader.GetCurrentValue(k))` show in status line?